# Unable to remove emails from Inbox

Tags: windows-xp, pop3, outlook-express

When I delete a mail in my Inbox on Outlook Express on XP, the mail isn't removed. It just stays there. No errors are showing, nothing happens.
What could be the problem preventing me from deleting mails?

Comment: Are you using POP or IMAP?

Comment: I am using pop.

Comment: I found it. There is a file containing all your removed files. If it gets to big Outlook Express or XP can't hadle it. You can fix it by removing Deleted Items.dbx and restarting outlook express

Location: C:\Documents and Settings\<Username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities\{randomstring}\Microsoft\Outlook Express.

Comment: @Jeff Consider posting your solution as an answer and accept it, so that it's more easy to find for others.

Comment: Wait until it happens to your Sent folder, then every time you send an email it sends it, tries to stick it in the Sent folder, it can't, so it puts it back in the Outbox which causes it to be sent again at the next send action, and repeat.....

Comment: Do not put the solution in the question; that's what the answer field is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found it. There is a file containing all your removed files. If it gets too big, Outlook Express or XP can't handle it. You can fix it by removing `Deleted Items.dbx` and restarting Outlook Express. The file's location is `C:\Documents and Settings\`*Username*`\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities\{`*randomstring*`}\Microsoft\Outlook Express`

Posted by [Jeff](https://superuser.com/users/67877/jeff) in the comments.

Just note: The `Local Settings` and `Application Data` folders are hidden by default.

Comment: No problem. Welcome back! I hope you stay

Comment: I would if I wasn't banned...

Comment: @Jeff You aren't currently banned on SU, and will never be banned from answering questions as long as they have the quality we require

Comment: If you have other answers that were deleted, you'll need to edit them to be great answers then